# What is the difference between a non-virtual method and a sealed method?

Tags: c#

I have a confusion I'd like to resolve .. In C#, only base class methods with the `virtual` tag can be overridden in derived classes. Base class methods without the `virtual` tag cannot be overridden. At best, derived classes can hide base class methods using `new`. Then we have `sealed` methods, which also cannot be overridden in base classes.

So then, what is the difference between a sealed method, and a standard non-virtual method ?

Another related question. Can base class `sealed` methods be replaced in derived classes using `new` ?

Comment: Sealed and Virtual keywords dont serve the same purpose. Sealed methods can be defined on Virtual methods

Comment: Your last question: The `new` modifier does not replace anything. It just tells the compiler to stop complaining when you introduce a **new** member in your class which has the same name (plus signature for methods) as an (inherited) member already present. Nothing is replaced. Both methods (members) are there, but are not related. One of the methods is **hidden** in some contexts, but it can still be found (and called) by casting the reference to a base type. Avoid using the `new` modifier; instead, choose an unused name for the new method.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`sealed` prevents any further overriding of the virtual methods up the chain.  You can only define `sealed` on methods that are overidden. Take a look at the docs for `sealed`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645769(v=vs.71).aspx

They give a great example of sealed usage:

```
using System;
class A
{
   public virtual void F() {
      Console.WriteLine("A.F");
   }
   public virtual void G() {
      Console.WriteLine("A.G");
   }
}
class B: A
{
   sealed override public void F() {
      Console.WriteLine("B.F");
   } 
   override public void G() {
      Console.WriteLine("B.G");
   } 
}
class C: B
{
   override public void G() {
      Console.WriteLine("C.G");
   } 
}
```

In this case anyone who derives off of `B` can override `G`, but not `F`.

Comment: Hmm.. that is example of `sealed` from C# spec. But where is non-virtual method and explanation of difference?

Comment: So `sealed` in a way, makes a `virtual` function, `non-virtual`, somewhere down the line ? I mean to say, `sealed` removes the `virtual` classification of a method ?

Comment: @Ahmad `sealed` indicates that this method has been overriden for the last time and you can't override it again if you derive.

Comment: So what I said above is correct, right ? Just so I'm understanding it correctly ..

Comment: Indeed, trying to apply `sealed` to a method with no `override` gives compile-time _error CS0238: 'FullMethodName' cannot be sealed because it is not an override_.

Answer (score 3):

If I read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/88c54tsw.aspx) correctly, sealed allows to stop virtual from being virtual. Essentially undoes virtual.

Comment: This isn't true.  The method is still virtual, the vtable will simply be limited to only those entries up until the method is `sealed`.  It's an important distinction.

Comment: @Servy, right this is exactly what I meant.  The class up the inheritance chain that marks virtual method as sealed essentially stops those classes that will inherit from it from seeing method as virtual (even though originally it was).  In other words, sealed keyword removes the earlier virtual keyword (at that level, not at level below.  Only at that level and above).

Answer (score 3):

The original poster asked two different questions:

1. What is the difference between a `sealed` method and a standard non-virtual method?
2. Can base class `sealed` methods be replaced in derived classes using `new`?

### Question 1 - Difference between `sealed` and non-virtual methods

If you don't want a child class to be able to access a new method that you are adding, creating non-virtual methods is the ideal solution. As an example, you may add a non-virtual method to a class that wasn't in its parent class.

However, sometimes your class's parent class has defined a method as `virtual` but you don't want any of your class's children to be able to override your specific `override` of this method. This is when you use `sealed`. It tells the compiler that the once `virtual` method can no longer be overriden. See the docs on `sealed` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/sealed).

### Question 2 - Can base class `sealed` methods be replaced using `new`

Yes, they can, though this may not do what you think. Replacing a `sealed` method does mean that calling that method will now call your implementation. However, if your class is ever cast into a reference to the parent class, the parent class's implementation of the method will be used, not yours. The Microsoft docs explain this [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/polymorphism#prevent-derived-classes-from-overriding-virtual-members).

The following example is slightly modified from Microsoft's docs:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("A"); }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("B"); }
}

public class C : B
{
    public sealed override void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("C"); }
}

public class D : C
{
    // Uncommenting the following line would cause a compilation error, since DoWork is sealed
    // public override void DoWork() { Console.WriteLine("D"); }
    
    public new void DoWork() {  Console.WriteLine("D"); }
}

...

// Later on in a class
D d = new D();
d.DoWork(); // Prints "D"

C c = d;
c.DoWork(); // Prints "C"
```

Answer (score 2):

Sealed methods can only be methods that override a method from the base class so no further overriding is possible.

From the docs :

> When an instance method declaration includes a sealed modifier, that
>   method is said to be a sealed method.
>   If an instance method
>   declaration includes the sealed modifier, it must also include the
>   override modifier.

This is not required for virtual methods.